# Openpyxl vs pd.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, performance, openpyxl

So this morning I came across this article https://saturncloud.io/blog/faster-way-to-read-excel-files-to-pandas-dataframe/ which claimed openpyxl was up to 10x faster than the regular `pd.read_excel`

This is the code I used

```
# Benchmarking read_excel()
start = time.time()
df = pd.read_excel(myfile, "data")
end = time.time()

print(f"read_excel() took {end - start:.2f} seconds")

# Benchmarking openpyxl and pandas
start = time.time()
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(myfile)
worksheet = workbook['data']
rows = []
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0])
end = time.time()
print(f"openpyxl and pandas took {end - start:.2f} seconds")
```

and the result seems quite wrong, any thoughts on why is the difference so big ?

[image]

Note that the file has 3 sheets but the only relevant one which holds a lot of data is the one called "data", the two other ones are small pivot table

Comment: tag: performance?

Comment: First, `read_excel` uses `openpyxl` so the benchmark is only comparing your hand-written loop against read_excel. Second, try adding *columns* instead of rows. Dataframes are built out of series (columns), not rows. Adding rows one by one has to modify all existing series.

Comment: It's also possible that `read_excel` uses the [optimized read-only mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html). The benchmark code doesn't. Try adding `, read_only=True` to `load_workbook`

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will try and update as soon as I can.
For the `read_only` part, correct me if I'm wrong but I thought I had seen somewhere that there were no `iter_cols | iter rows` methods for read only worksheets ?

Comment: The linked docs show an iteration example, so no

Comment: This may be  a matter of the actual Pandas version and probably Python as well. With Python 3.11 and Pandas 2.1, when I try this example with `read_only=True` I get similar performance. When I don't use it, `read_excel` is about 30-40% faster. There's no 10x difference like the example you posted. The file *size* may also affect performance

Comment: The openpyxl documentation contains examples of how to use optimised modes and Pandas. This code will be slower because it deviates from that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the for loop in your script

You should try with something like:

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(myfile)
worksheet = workbook['data']

data = worksheet.values

columns = next(data)[0:]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```